# Exporting an archive for Enterprise Deployment in XCode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I can archive my project in XCode 6 and choose the Enterprise Deployment Option.  In XCode 5 when you go to choose the location of the archive on the file system you get a check box that says "Save for Enterprise" and you get several other options to complete like url.  This generates the plist file.  I dont get that in Xcode 6, just the ipa.  Is this because XCode 6 is Beta?  Or do you no longer get a plist as well as the ipa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't get a plist either so I used a trick.

To distribute my app Over The Air anyway, I used a plist formerly generated with XCode 5 and changed manually the link to my newly generated IPA.

Once you managed to do that, there is one last thing to know. When you'll open the link to the plist, you'll have the impression that nothing happens because iOS don't close you current window + slide to the downloaded app anymore. But it doesn't necessarily mean that nothing happen! Go to your home screen manually and check.

### UPDATE

If that still doesn't work, try this workaround: change your bundle ID, generate your new App ID and provisioning profile accordingly, regenerate your IPA and redo the above. For some, it works only the first time for a given bundle ID!

Comment: So whats actually the real way to do it?

Comment: This is what I would like to know as well.

Comment: So I'm having the issue where tapping "Install" on the popup does nothing. I press the home button and nothing has been installed. Any other steps I'm missing?

Comment: I added an additional workaround. Can you please tell me if it works for you as well?

Comment: For me, all was perfect in Xcode5, now I'm getting this message, http://i.imgur.com/Hp6jIWJ.png . Any idea please?